# retrieve all rows from the table grouped by condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql table:

```
products
```

with a fileds:

```
id, product_group_id, internal_product_id, version, platform_id, name

1   12                12                   1        30           Megacalculator              
2   12                12                   2        30           Megacalculator            
3   16                17                   1        30           Calculator                    
4   16                17                   2        30           Calculator
5   16                18                   0.1      40           Calculator Linux
6   20                19                   2.1      30           Converter Windows
7   20                20                   2.1      40           Converter Linux
8   30                24                   0.1      30           Editor
```

I need to retrieve all rows from this table grouped by 'product_group_id' but with a different 'internal_product_id' inside of the group. Also, the rows count in each group must be equal to some special number(the value must be supplied into the query as an external parameter)

For example:

external parameter = 2, result:

```
product_group_id    
16                  
20
```

external parameter = 1, result:

```
product_group_id    
12                  
30
```

Please help me with this sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

for parameter = 2

```
    select `product_group_id` from products
    group by `product_group_id`
    having count(distinct `internal_product_id`) = 2
```

for parameter = 1

```
    select `product_group_id` from products 
    group by `product_group_id`
    having count(distinct `internal_product_id`) = 1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07b551/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
select product_group_id from products 
group by product_group_id;
having count(internal_product_id) = 2;
```

Or you can get the information in a table:

```
select product_group_id, count(internal_product_id) from products 
group by product_group_id;
```